# Magento install two languages not stores

Tags: magento

I am new to magento. When I install another language. Following [this](http://www.templatemonster.com/help/how-to-install-a-new-language.html) tutorial.

But the issue is it creates two stores or store views. I don't want to create two stores I just need two languages. That's it.

Help!

Comment: Since this is no programming specific question, maybe http://magento.stackexchange.com/ would be more helpful.

Comment: So, you mean one store view have two languages?

Comment: @Thiha, no two languages for one store view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Languages are set at the store level in Magento. You will need to create two stores. As long as you don't need to set anything else at the store level, continue setting configuration and catalog data at the global or website levels.